# Trying to extract some data from a webpage (scraping beginner)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract some data from a webpage using **Requests** and then **Beautifulsoup**. I started by getting the html code with Requests and then "putting it" in Beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


result = requests.get("https://XXXXX")
#print(result.status_code)
#print(result.headers)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
```

Then I singled out some pieces of code:

```
tags = soup.findAll('ol',{'class':'activity-popup-users'})

print(tags)
```

Here is a part of what I got:

```
<div class="account js-actionable-user js-profile-popup-actionable " data-emojified-name="" data-feedback-token="" data-impression-id="" data-name="The UN Times" data-screen-name="TheUNTimes" data-user-id="3787869561">
```

What I want now is to extract the data after `data-user-id=`which consists of numbers between `""`. Then I would like that data to be entered into some kind of calc sheet.
I am an absolute beginner and I'm postly pasting code I found elsewhere on tutorials or documentation. 
Thanks a lot for your time...

EDIT:
So here's what I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
result = requests.get("https://XXXX")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.findAll('ol',{'class':'activity-popup-users'})
print(tags['data-user-id'])
```

And here's what I got:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So I tried that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
result = requests.get("https://XXXX") 
src = result.content soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
#tags = soup.findAll('a',{'class':'account-group js-user-profile-link'}) 
tags = soup.findAll('ol',{'class':'activity-popup-users'}) 
tags.attrs
#print(tags['data-user-id'])
```

And got:

```
File "C:\Users\XXXX\element.py", line 1884, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'attrs'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any attribute value of a tag by treating the tag like an attribute-value dictionary.

[Read the BeautifulSoup documentation on attributes.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

```
tag['data-user-id']
```

For example

```
html="""
<div class="account js-actionable-user js-profile-popup-actionable " data-emojified-name="" data-feedback-token="" data-impression-id="" data-name="The UN Times" data-screen-name="TheUNTimes" data-user-id="3787869561">
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
tag=soup.find('div')
print(tag['data-user-id'])
```

Output

```
3787869561
```

Edit to include OP's question change:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
result = requests.get("http://twitter.com/RussiaUN/media")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div',class_='account')
#just print
for div in divs:
    print(div['data-user-id'])
#write to a file    
with open('file.txt','w') as f:
   for div in divs:
        f.write(div['data-user-id']+'\n')
```

Output:

```
255471924
2154112404
408696260
1267887043
475954041
3787869561
796979978
261711504
398068796
1174451010
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I did that:
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
result = requests.get("https://twitter.com/RussiaUN/media")
#print(result.status_code)
#print(result.headers)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
#tags = soup.findAll('a',{'class':'account-group js-user-profile-link'})
#tags = soup.findAll('ol',{'class':'activity-popup-users'})
tag = soup.find('div')
print(tag['data-user-id'])
#print(tags.attrs)`

And it says that: 
`KeyError: 'data-user-id'`

Comment: @MaxBaldwin are you trying to get all the data-user-id from all divs with account class?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract all the data-user-id from the document.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin See my edit. findAll returns a list of tags/ elements not a single tag. You have to loop through it to get an single tag and the do tag['data-user-id']

Comment: last question:
Why did we have to put an _ between find and all and between class and ='account'
?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin B'coz 'class' is a built in keyword of python and this is the convention used by bs4 to avoid conflict.

Comment: And how can you store the resulting data in a file? Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you recommend a website or pdf to learn a bit by myself?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html , https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/,  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/